# Forgiving JavaScript validation for US phone numbers and allowing extensions (jquery allowed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Perhaps a forgiving JavaScript solution would only make sure that only valid characters are allowed. (digits, dashes, periods, letters for extension.

Although loop seems best, is there a simple regular expression that checks for valid characters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation/123666#123666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression is just javascript, not jQuery. What is the format you seek? How many letters are allowed in the extension? I could [look it up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan), but it would help greatly if you would do that. It seems numbers from 7 to 11 digits are allowed.

It is nice to allow users to enter phone numbers in block of 3 or 4 characters because it is much easier for them to read, like:

```
914-499-1900
```

or

```
914 499 1900
```

or similar. Trim the spaces for validation or storage if you like.

For the above formats exactly:

```
function testPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  var re = /^\d{3}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$/;
  return re.test(phoneNumber);
}
```

Or you can remove unnecessary but allowed characters and test what remains:

```
function testPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  var re = /^\d{10}$/;
  return re.test(phoneNumber.replace(/[ -+]/g,''));
}
```

But these don't allow for extension. If you provide the format, the regular expression part is easy.

Comment: This is not exactly what we used, but it jump started us in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex:    `\d|\.|\-`

Although technically you want the opposite `[^\d\.\-]` so you can do a replace ->

```
$('input').blur(function() {

   var value = $(this).val();
   $(this).val(value.replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, ''));

});
```

See fiddle in action - http://jsfiddle.net/GspT4/

Comment: interesting. I tried it out in jsfiddle and that is neat!